# ASN1 OBJECT_IDENTIFIER decoding

Tags: decoding, asn.1, crypto++

I have the following ASN1 data

```
Sequence
  Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier
  Sequence
    Sequence
      Integer
      Integer
    Sequence
      Integer
      Integer
```

My goal is to get the encoded integer values. My code so far is the following

```
ByteQueue queue(inputLen);
queue.Put2(input, inputLen, 0, false);

BERSequenceDecoder outer(queue);

BERSequenceDecoder discard(outer); // unnecessary  sequence with object_identifier
BERSequenceDecoder obj(discard,
    CryptoPP::ASNTag::OBJECT_IDENTIFIER | CryptoPP::ASNIdFlag::UNIVERSAL);

BERSequenceDecoder parent(outer); //BER decode error
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    BERSequenceDecoder dataSequence(parent);
    Integer i1, i2;

    i1.BERDecode(dataSequence);
    i2.BERDecode(dataSequence);
```

Problem is, I don't know how to properly get past the object_identifier part, at least I think that is the problem. I'm getting `BER decode error` on the 4. decoder object.

Also, am I initializing the ByteQueue correctly? this `Put2` method doesn't seem like the correct way, but I didn't find any other methods.

Comment: You might also want to check out at [How to decode non-key ASN1 data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29652055)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ByteQueue queue(inputLen);
> queue.Put2(input, inputLen, 0, false);
> ```

You could also do something like:

```c++
ArraySource as(input, inputLen, false /*pumpAll*/);
as.TransferTo(queue);
```

Or, if you just want to copy them:

```c++
as.CopyTo(queue);
```

---

> Problem is, I don't know how to properly get past the object_identifier part...

I would probably do something like:

```
byte b = as.Peek();
if(b == /*some tag*/)
    as.Skip(n);
```

Or:

```
byte b = as.Peek();
if(b == /*some tag*/)
{
    lword length;
    bool definiteLength;

    if(!BERLengthDecode(as, length, definiteLength))
        throw BadParam();

    as.Skip(length);
}
```

The source files with the goodies like above is [`asn.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/asn_8h_source.html) and [`asn.cpp`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/asn_8cpp_source.html). The others you might be interested in include `BERDecodeOctetString` and `BERDecodeBitString`.

Comment: This has been very helpful, as `Peek()` makes debugging very easy. Problem is, that there seems to be no `Discard()` method for neither ArraySource or ByteQueue. How to skip bytes?

Comment: @Kelo - My bad... Its called `Skip`. See the [BufferedTransformation Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_buffered_transformation.html). Sources, Filters and Sinks all inherit from it (`ArraySource` and `ByteQueue` are examples of sources. A `ByteQueue` can be a sink, too).